# NSDate and double precision problem

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, double-precision

Here is the code

```
NSDate* d = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:32.4560];
double ti = [d timeIntervalSince1970];
NSLog(@"Interval: %f %f %f %f",ti,32.4560,ti*1000.0,32.4560*1000.0);
```

the output is

> Interval: 32.456000 32.456000 32455.999970 32456.000000

Why NSDate return the value which lose some precisions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's not the problem of `NSDate` itself. It's in the nature of the floating point numbers themselves. I believe `NSDate` keeps its date from the OS X epoch(2001), not the UNIX epoch (1970). Let the difference in the two epochs be x.

Then what happens is this:

```
NSDate* d = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:32.4560];
// at this point, d keeps 32.4560 + x
double ti = [d timeIntervalSince1970];
// ti is then (32.4560+x)-x
```

However, the floating point doesn't have infinite precision. So, `+x` and then `-x` can introduce slight error in the calculation.

For more, read e.g. [this Wikipedia article.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems)

If you use the OS X epoch, you get what you naively expect:

```
NSDate* d = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:32.4560];
// at this point, d keeps 32.4560 + 0
double ti = [d timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
// ti is then (32.4560+0)-0, which is 32.4560 even in the floating point world.
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know OSX epoch is 2001.

Comment: Maybe I should've used the terminology "OpenStep epoch" instead. See http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/802-2112/6i63mn64s?l=en&a=view#05.Classes-81  I believe OpenStep specification came before 2001. It's quite ambitious of them to set the reference date in the future.